# Java Regex "-[0-9]{0,}" seems to match "-abc"

Tags: java, regex

Regex:

```
"-[0-9]{0,}"
```

String:

```
"-abc"
```

According to the test [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html), that should not happen. I assume I'm doing something wrong in my code.

Code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "-abc";

    String regex = "-[0-9]{0,}";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        if (matcher.group().length() == 0)
            break;

        // get the number less the dash
        int beginIndex = matcher.start();
        int endIndex = matcher.end();
        String number = s.substring(beginIndex + 1, endIndex);

        s = s.replaceFirst(regex, "negative " + number);
    }

    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Some context: The speech synthesis program I use cannot pronounce numbers with a leading negative sign, so it must be replaced with the word "negative".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
-[0-9]{0,}
```

means your sting must have `-`, then could be **`0` or `more`** numbers.

so `-abc` is **`0`** number case

you didn't specify `^ and $`, so your regex matches `foo-bar` or `lll-0` even `abc-` as well

Answer (score 2):

`{0,}` has exactly the same meaning as `*`. You regexp thus means *"a dash that **can be** followed by digits"*. `-abc` contains a dash, so the pattern get found.

`-\d+` should suit your needs better (don't forget to escape the backslash for java: `-\\d+`).

If you want the whole string to match the pattern, anchor your regexp with `^` and `$`: `^-\d+$`.

Comment: @fardjad This will match `"-"` too.